# What is the advised way to populate a persistent collection with the results of a query in mongo?

Tags: python, mongodb

The obvious way is to do `find` and then iterate the cursor and insert elements one by one. This seems inefficient to me.

Another way is to define a map-reduce on the query results, which would not reduce anything and use the out parameter to specify the target collection. This seems like a hack.

Is there a more efficient and straightforward way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you have to use the workarounds as you describe, the feature you refer to has been requested but is not yet implemented:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-610

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2920

Vote and/or comment on them with a use case to get them some attention.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about efficiency, you can run the query server side with `eval()`

```
> e_query
function e_query() {
    db.collection1.find({...}).forEach(
        function(obj){
            db.collection2.insert(obj);
        }
    );
}
> db.eval(e_query)
```

Comment: Yes, we are. I am not interested in an array. I am talking about a permanent collection. If the query results in a large volume of data, turning it first into an array does not seem like a good thing to do.

Comment: Mongodb returns cursors. If you want to use the results in a permanent collection, you will have to do two things: 1) get the data, 2) populate a collection. What's wrong with an array? It allows you to get the data once and you get a ready made collection. (we're in javacsript land here, so there's really no other collection types.)

Comment: I am talking about a permanent collection, the one shows with the `use collections` command.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Why not use eval() to run the query server side?